# c# program list

Tags: c#

could some body provide me program list which will open my mind and will help me to do good codes.
i searched it on net but couldn't find any good link.

Any stuff like web links or any thing will be greatly appreciated .

Comment: What are you looking for? It's not very clear. What is a "program list"? See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx

Comment: Poor guy, there is no magic going on, just hard work and a desire to be the best.

Comment: i want to know some good code and logical programs which can improve my programing skills nothing more then this, i just want to know programs as assignment not want the all code for each program .. so that i can give my hands on those program and if no able to do then gain assistance from u experts..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/forum/118-c-programmers/